# Image Transforms: Is there a way to detect portrait or landscape?

Tags: assets, image-transforms

I'm looking to setup an image transform via the control panel but I only want to resize the image (scale - not crop or fit). The trouble is that I don't know whether the uploaded image will be a portrait or a landscape. Is there a way to set it to just scale to a maximum bounding box?

For example, if I want images to be a maximum 1000px width or height (whichever the longer edge is), how can I set that and maintain aspect ratio?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best way would be to use the [Fit image transform](https://craftcms.com/docs/image-transforms).

Set the transform to 'Fit' and set both your width and height values to 1000px. That way the image will continue to scale until the first longest edge reaches 1000px.